# Micronaut HTTP Client - Deserialize generic type - For API Testing

Tags: java, junit, jackson, micronaut, micronaut-client

For API testing I have to parse the response of a request using io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient

I prefer to use the format given below.

```java
Response<User> response =
                client.toBlocking().retrieve(HttpRequest.POST("/", user), Response.class);
```

But It is not working. I am getting type cast error while trying to fetch User from response

```java
User user = response.getUser();
```

Currently I am using *ObjectMapper* (Jackson) like given below,

```java
String response = client.toBlocking().retrieve(HttpRequest.POST("/", user), String.class);
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Response<User> response = objectMapper.readValue(response, new TypeReference<Response<User>>() {});
```

Is there any way to use *TypeReference* directly with *HttpClient* retrieve method? Or any other way to use generic class type with *HttpClient*.

Other useful informations

```java
// Response generic class
class Response<T> {
T data;
....
}
```

Sample response

```
{
    "data": {
        "name":"sample"
    },
    "message": "Success"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options:

If you need only that `User` object instance you can do it by `retrieve()` method where the second parameter is the domain class (`User` in your case) and then you can use the `user` variable as you need:

```java
User user = client.toBlocking().retrieve(HttpRequest.POST("/", user), User.class);

assertThat(user)
    .isNotNull()
    .extracting(User::getName)
    .isEqualTo("sample");
```

---

If you need also response object (for example to be able to check response code) then you should use `exchange()` method and then get the `User` instance by calling `body()` method on that response:

```java
HttpResponse<User> response = client.toBlocking()
    .exchange(HttpRequest.POST("/", user), User.class);

assertThat(response)
    .isNotNull()
    .extracting(HttpResponse::body)
    .extracting(User::getName)
    .isEqualTo("sample");
```

---

**Update**: When you need to use generic class as a response then you have to use `Argument.of()` as a second parameter of the `retrieve()` and `exchange()` methods where you can specify response generic class and its type parameters. See the example:

```java
Response<User> response = client.toBlocking()
    .retrieve(HttpRequest.POST("/", user), Argument.of(Response.class, User.class));

assertThat(response)
    .isNotNull()
    .extracting(Response::getData)
    .extracting(User::getName)
    .isEqualTo("sample");
```

If you do it without `Argument.of()` then it will convert `data` property into `LinkedHashMap` instead of `User` and this:

```java
Response<User> response = client.toBlocking().retrieve(HttpRequest.POST("/", user), Response.class);
response.getData().getName();
```

... will throw `ClassCastException`:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be
>   cast to class my.app.domain.User (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module
>   java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; my.app.domain.User.User is in unnamed
>   module of loader 'app')

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer.

Response is a custom generic class to wrap the api response. So the proper type of the deserialized api response in question would be Response<User>.

Eg. Response 
class Response <T>{
T data;
<other fields>
}

I want to extract the data field from Response<User> type.

Comment: OK, sorry, I misunderstood your question. So I added also an example with generic class as a response.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a very simple alternative: When your responses are JSON, you can always simply deserialize them to `Map.class`. Quick & easy. Of course then you do not have a type safety.